# Deleting sequence of 2 or more elements from an array in c++ using a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to c++ programming and I am having problems writing this function. I already wrote some code (see below) but i do not know what is wrong. please help me. Thanks.

**Here is the array: char marbles[10] = {'B', 'G', 'R', 'P', 'B', 'G', 'R', 'P', 'B', 'G'};**

(a) This function takes in a character array and the size of that array, and deletes the element at offset pos. Elements at offsets greater than pos are all shifted over to fill in the gap. 
This is my code but I am not sure if it is right.

```
void deletePosition(char arr[], int size, int pos) 
{ 
    for (int i = pos; i < size - 1; i = i + 1) 
        { 
           arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; 
        } 
        size = size - 1; 
}
```

(b)This function takes in an array of characters representing a sequence of coloured marbles along with the size of the array. It deletes all sequences of 2 or more marbles that share the same colour and returns the new size of the array as a result of the deletions. The "deletePosition" function (above - part (a)) should be used to perform the individual deletions.

This is my code but I don't know what's wrong

```
int deleteMarbles(char marbles[], int size) 
{ 
     int i, j; 
     for (i = 1; i < size; i=i+1) 
     { 
        for (j=0; j<i; j=j+1) 
        { 
            if (marbles[i] == marbles[j]) 
            { 
                 deletePosition(marbles, size, i); 
                 deletePosition(marbles, size, j); 
            } 
        } 
      } 
return size; 
}
```

Comment: Debug it and find out. (and if that `deletePostion` function is mandated by your instructor for use in doing this they're teaching a *terrible* algorithm. A long string of similar-marbles will result in repeatedly copying the same data over and over again).

Comment: you are using outdated index after deleting elements from marbles

Answer (score 1):

Your `deletePostion()` needs to take `size` by reference:

```
void deletePosition(char arr[], int& size, int pos)
```